# tftpd allows connections, but times out transferring a file

Tags: ubuntu, tftp

I'm runnung Ubuntu 12.04 in a VirtualBox VM. I've installed the `tftpd-hpa` package. I'm using this to boot an embedded Linux system, and I've noticed that on first boot of my VM, it wouldn't work, but restarting the `tftpd-hpa` service made it work every time, until next boot.

Today, I ran a shell script from Texas Instruments that may have mucked with my tftpd configuration, and now I cannot get it to work at all. I'm able to connect, but transfers timeout, even to localhost (I also tried 127.0.0.1):

```
steve@steve-VirtualBox:~$ tftp
tftp> connect localhost
tftp> status
Connected to localhost.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
tftp> get zImage
Transfer timed out.

tftp>
```

Note that `/var/lib/tftpboot/zImage` does exist, however I get the exact same behavior for a file that doesn't exist.

Here are the contents of `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa`:

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

Here is `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp`:

```
service tftp
{
protocol = udp
port = 69
socket_type = dgram
wait = yes
user = nobody
server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args = /var/lib/tftpboot
disable = no
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you're starting tftpd-hpa from xinetd and as a standalone service at the same time. Please choose one and disable the other.

E.g. set `disable = yes` in `/etc/xinetd.d/tftp` and restart xinetd.
Then restart the standalone service `service tftpd-hpa restart` and try the connection again.

Comment: It seems like this has resolved my new problem, but I still have to restart tftpd-hpa after a reboot before it will work (which wasn't what this question was about). Thank you!

Comment: For the follow on question to hopefully resolve the other part, see http://serverfault.com/questions/599126/tftpd-hpa-service-must-be-restarted-before-working-after-fresh-boot

Answer (score 1):

Setting TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69" didn't work for me, at least for both interfaces.
Setting `TFTP_ADDRESS=":69"` did the job

Comment: Can you clarify your OS and its version?

Comment: It's Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

1) uninstall/re-install tftpd-hpa

2) add to /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

```
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to poke a hole in the firewall. From step 4 of http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/02/guide-on-tftp-server-setup-in-fedora/:

> Insert the following line before the “COMMIT” line of
>   /etc/sysconfig/iptables and then restart the service with ‘service
>   iptables restart':
>
> -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 69 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216495/7286).

I had to edit `/etc/default/tftpd-hpa` and set the IP address in the `TFTP_ADDRESS=` variable.

That was on Debian Jessie, but it may be the same on Ubuntu.